# Let $T_k$ be a sequence of $n\times n$ positive matrices such that

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, inner-products, matrix-calculus

Let $\{T_k\}$ be a sequence of $n\times n$ positive matrices such that
$$\lim\limits_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{N}\sum\limits_{k=1}^N T_k=0.$$

I want to see whether this ensures existence of a sub-sequence $T_{n_k}$ which converges to $0$. By [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4768862/if-the-average-sequence-converges-to-zero-does-a-subsequence-converge-to-zero?noredirect=1&lq=1), I know that this result holds for non-negative matrices real numbers. This result [does not hold for arbitrary $C^*$-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4845330/775129). I want to see what happens for positive matrices. By positive matrix $T$, I mean that $\langle Th,h\rangle\ge 0$ for all $h$.

What I have tried is as follows: Let us denote $S_N=\frac{1}{N}\sum\limits_{k=1}^N T_k$ and let $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ be the standard orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{C}^n$. Then

$$\langle S_Ne_1,e_1\rangle =\frac{1}{N}\sum\limits_{k=1}^N \langle T_k e_1,e_1\rangle$$

Then there exists a subsequence $T_{n_k}$ such that $\langle T_{n_k} e_1,e_1\rangle\to0$. Now, I want to get a subsequence of this $T_{n_k}$ (say $T_{m_l}$) such that $\langle T_{m_l} e_2,e_2\rangle\to0$. This way I want to get a final subsequence (say $T_{i_j}$) of $T_k$ such that $\langle T_{i_j} e_k,e_k\rangle\to0$ for all $k$ by induction. But the problem is the Cesaro sum of $T_{n_k}$ may not converge to $0$. This is creating the main issue while applying the induction.

Can anyone help me with any kind of idea or hint? Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about $\langle Te_1,e_1\rangle+\langle Te_2,e_2\rangle+\ldots+\langle Te_n,e_n\rangle$. *Remember, it is a fact that for any positive-definite matrix, the entry with the largest absolute value must be on the diagonal and furthermore all the diagonal entries are positive.*

---

> Since $\dfrac{\text{trace}(T_1)+\text{trace}(T_2)+\ldots+\text{trace}(T_N)}{N}\to_{N\to\infty}0$, you get some subsequence $T_{j_k}$ such that $\text{trace}(T_{j_k})\to_{k\to\infty}0$.